# How to track down file not found errors when debugging Android apps built with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build an apk from an existing web application. The build finishes and the app launches but, when I inspect the app in Chrome I'm getting file not found errors. The app loads perfectly in the web browser so I know the paths are correct. I'm a bit confused. Is there a way to track down file not found errors like this?

Comment: Does your app build into a separate folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... it builds into an apk. I'm pretty new at this, sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: I understood your question as you were getting the main page to load but other items weren't loading. I was getting at the fact that your HTML/JS etc. is probably copied elsewhere before going into the APK. Depending on your build process, it is at the very least somewhere in /platforms/android. The other files probably aren't making it there.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, it's building into /platforms/andriod and I can see that the file in question is indeed present in that path.

Comment: Is it inside platformwww?

Comment: No, none of the actual project files are in there. That director only contains files created by the build process.

Comment: Yes, my fault. Check assets/www and see if the files are in there.

Comment: The file IS in assets/www however, I unzipped the apk and the file in question is not present there. So that explains the file not found error -- the question now, however is how do I get that file into the apk?